# Not able to scroll down in notebook

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I created a tcl notebook, it have two tabs, if the file is too big, i am not able to scroll down. Sharing my code here.
To execute this code, you need 2 files (Warning.txt and Error.txt), place them into same directory before running this code.
Please create two files Error.txt and Warning.txt.
Put some content to it make it some 10,000 lines.

```
#!/usr/bin/wish -f
#
package require Tk

proc noteb {} {
    global rundir logfile
    frame .lpo
    pack .lpo -side top -fill both -expand true
    #cd $rundir
    set ft [exec grep -c Warning ./Warning.txt]
    puts $ft
    set ert [exec grep -c Error ./Error.txt]
    puts $ert
    pack [frame .fa] -fill both -side top
    pack [ttk::notebook .fa.nb] -fill both
    set gt "Errors"
    set bt "Warnings"
    set delim ":"
    set rt [concat [string trim $bt][string trim $delim][string trim $ft]]
    set dt [concat [string trim $gt][string trim $delim][string trim $ert]]

    if {$ft > 0} {
        .fa.nb add [frame .fa.nb.f1] -text $rt
    } else {
        .fa.nb add [frame .fa.nb.f1] -text "Warnings"
    }
    pack [frame .fa.nb.f1.f11] -side top -fill both -expand true
    pack [text .fa.nb.f1.f11.t1 -bg LightYellow -borderwidth 2 -width 80 -height 6 -relief raised -setgrid true ] -side left -fill both -expand true
    scrollbar .fa.nb.f1.f11.scroll -command {.fa.nb.f1.f11.t1 yview}
    pack .fa.nb.f1.f11.scroll -side right -fill y
    set fp1 [open Warning.txt r]
    set v [read $fp1]
    .fa.nb.f1.f11.t1 insert 1.0 $v
    close $fp1

    if {$ert > 0} {
        .fa.nb add [frame .fa.nb.f2] -text $dt
    } else {
        .fa.nb add [frame .fa.nb.f2] -text "Errors"
    }

    pack [frame .fa.nb.f2.f11] -side top  -fill both -expand true
    pack [text .fa.nb.f2.f11.t1 -bg LightYellow -borderwidth 2  -width 80 -height 6 -relief raised -setgrid true ] -side left -fill both -expand true
    scrollbar .fa.nb.f2.f11.scroll -command {.fa.nb.f2.f11.t1 yview}
    pack .fa.nb.f2.f11.scroll -side right -fill y
    set fp [open Error.txt r]
    set c [read $fp]
    .fa.nb.f2.f11.t1 insert 1.0 $c
    close $fp
}

button .mn -text summary -command {noteb}
pack .mn -side left
```

Answer (score 2):

In these lines below, you tell the scrollbar about the text widget, but not the text widget about the scrollbar. You need to do both.

```
pack [text .fa.nb.f1.f11.t1 -bg LightYellow -borderwidth 2 -width 80 -height 6 -relief raised -setgrid true ] -side left -fill both -expand true
scrollbar .fa.nb.f1.f11.scroll -command {.fa.nb.f1.f11.t1 yview}
pack .fa.nb.f1.f11.scroll -side right -fill y
```

Let that instead become this:

```
text .fa.nb.f1.f11.t1 -bg LightYellow -borderwidth 2 -width 80 -height 6 \
        -relief raised -setgrid true -yscroll {.fa.nb.f1.f11.scroll set}
scrollbar .fa.nb.f1.f11.scroll -command {.fa.nb.f1.f11.t1 yview}

pack .fa.nb.f1.f11.t1 -side left -fill both -expand true
pack .fa.nb.f1.f11.scroll -side right -fill y
```

Though I'd actually be inclined to do this instead:

```
set w .fa.nb.f1.f11
text $w.t1 -bg LightYellow -borderwidth 2 -width 80 -height 6 -relief raised \
        -setgrid true -yscroll [list $w.scroll set]
scrollbar $w.scroll -command [list $w.t1 yview]

pack $w.t1 -side left -fill both -expand true
pack $w.scroll -side right -fill y
```

Putting the container widget name in a variable helps keep your code more sensible, and makes it more obvious that the text and scrollbar are related. (It also makes it easier to refactor the code, if desired.)

Answer (score 1):

I think it will work if you set the -yscroll option on the text widget.